# Rest template exchange method working incorrectly

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am consuming another restful web service that's https inside my rest WS.  When I am running my application on localachine the code works fine. But as soon as I deploy it and then access my application through that url, that rest template call written inside my code gives 400 error.

Here is the log trace

```
400 Bad Request
: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 Bad Request
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:76)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:524)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:481)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForObject(RestTemplate.java:317)
    at com.pekam.myandroid.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:106)
    at com.pekam.myandroid.MainActivity$HttpRequestTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: post the code and stack trace so that we can help you.

Comment: I have added the logs in the description

Comment: Check your request xml....you are missing some mandatory attributes ...Get the request xml from logs and do a check in postman

Comment: 400 means it hits the server but some problem in your request xml

Comment: I checked it when I run the same code on local machine that rest template call works fine....but as I deploy my application on server and tries to hit it via rest client, the rest template call gives 400 error

Comment: restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);

Comment: This is the call written inside my code which works fine when I run my application on local machine. Bit gives 400 when the deployed jar is hit through(the route is my request hits apigee tool and then it comes to my deployed jar)

Comment: The entity you are posting is wrong....Your local machine and host machine both points to the same endpoint of the webservice?

Comment: Yes same.And for the entity..that piece of code works fine on my local machine

Comment: something you are missing in your request a header or content-type etc in your requets

Comment: But if this so how come it's working fine on my local

Comment: Share your postman call or curl here and share the entire client code....Let's see what could be the issue

Comment: or refer this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019212/org-springframework-web-client-httpclienterrorexception-400-bad-request

Comment: I checked it from server some how application was not able to pick one header which was the problem....but thanks for all the suggestions

Comment: Hope finally it resolved your issue...Happy to help you

Comment: I posted our conversation as an answer. Could you please accept the answer and upvote it so that it will be helpful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there should be an issue in your request. Either you are missing mandatory request parameters in your request XML or missing some headers which throw this 400 Bad request exception.

Please follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38019212/org-springframework-web-client-httpclienterrorexception-400-bad-request).It may resolve your issue. Let us know for any issue.